# jqGrid sorting is not working

Tags: php, jquery, jqgrid

Following is my code. I want to sort the data by clicking on the table header. But it is not working.

```
 $("#list_records").jqGrid({
                    url: 'ajaxFetchTableInfo.php?table=GET_TRAINING_TYPE',
                    editurl: 'ajaxSaveTrainingType.php',
                    datatype: "json",
                    colNames: ["TRAINING TYPE ID", "TRAINING TYPE NAME", "REMARKS"],
                    colModel: [
                        {
                            label: 'TRAINING_TYPE_ID',
                            name: 'TRAINING_TYPE_ID',
                            index: 'TRAINING_TYPE_ID',
                            editable:true,
                            sortable:true,
                            sorttype: "text",
                            editoptions:{readonly:"readonly"},
                            width: 75                        
                        },
                        {
                            label : 'TRAINING_TYPE_NAME',
                            name: 'TRAINING_TYPE_NAME',
                            index: 'TRAINING_TYPE_NAME',
                            width: 140,
                            editable: true, // must set editable to true if you want to make the field editable
                            editoptions: {size:50, maxlength: 80},
                            editrules:{required: true, maxlength: 80},
                            sortable:true,
                            sorttype: "text",
                            // set options related to the layout of the Edit and Add Forms
                            formoptions: {
                                colpos: 1, // the position of the column
                                rowpos: 2, // the position of the row
                                label: "Training Type Name:", // the label to show for each input control  
                                elmsuffix: "(*)"                 

                            }
                        },
                        {
                            label : 'Remarks',
                            name: 'REMARKS',
                            width: 100,
                            editable: true,
                            edittype: 'textarea',
                            editoptions:{rows:3, cols:45},
                            formoptions: {
                                colpos: 1,
                                rowpos: 3
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    loadOnce : true,
                    viewrecords: true,
                    altRows: true,
                    width: 780,
                    height: 200,
                    rowNum: 10,
                    rowList:[10, 20, 30],
                    caption:"Training Type Information",
                    sortname: 'TRAINING_TYPE_ID',
                    sortorder: "asc",
                    emptyrecords: "No Records to Display.",
                    //footerrow: true,
                    pager: "#perpage"
                });
```

Comment: check this one example. Would help you http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace `loadOnce : true` to `loadonce : true`. The server should return *all* data (all pages) from the server (`url: 'ajaxFetchTableInfo.php?table=GET_TRAINING_TYPE'`).

Comment: When I replaced loadOnce : true to loadonce : true, it is doing sorting just fine. But When I am adding a new row or editing the existing one, It is not loading the changes until a page refresh. What can I do for sorting and update real time changes?

Comment: In response to "ajaxFetchTableInfo.php?table=GET_TRAINING_TYPE" ,  My code are as follows:  if($table == 'GET_TRAINING_TYPE')
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM EL_TRAINING_TYPE";  
 $rs = exec_sql($sql);

        if (!$rs) {
  echo "Failed. Error: ".$rs;
 }
 else{
  echo get_json($rs);
 }